# How to fix value-change table based on a number that exists on the same page

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I need to create table that will show 6 values in it. This 6 values should be changed based on one number that is available on this page in . **Lets call that number X**. 
This means that when X fits in some of the ranges (which should be 13) then all 6 prices should be changed at once. Which means that variations are **n(number of ranges) = number of scenarios because** if X is in one range it changes all the 6 prices at one.

I have 2 problems(I am not that good with JS and I plan to use this challenge as starting point of learning it):

1. I tried to do the table but I struggle to understand how to make the number X value of var.
2. If this approach with if else ok because it looks pritty general to me and I it will became huge then add all 13 ranges.

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;border-color:black;}
.tg .tg-s268{text-align:left}
.tg .tg-0lax{text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="column-title-1"></th>
    <th class="column-title-2">Summer</th>
    <th class="column-title-3">Winter</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="row-title-1">Store 1</td>
    <td id="premium-price-1">no price</td>
    <td id="premium-price-2">no price</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="row-title-2">Store 2</td>
    <td id="deductible-price-1">no price</td>
    <td id="deductible-price-2">no price</td>
  </tr>

    <tr>
    <td id="row-title-3">Store 3</td>
    <td id="replacement-price-1">no price</td>
    <td id="replacement-price-2">no price</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<!-- AVAILABLE SOMEWHERE ON THE PAGE--><p><span id="price-amount">240</span></p>
```

```
var loose = document.getElementsByClassName("price-amount");

if (100 < loose && loose < 200) {
document.getElementById("premium-price-1").innerHTML = "18";
document.getElementById("premium-price-2").innerHTML = "20";
document.getElementById("deductible-price-1").innerHTML = "120";
document.getElementById("deductible-price-2").innerHTML = "130";
document.getElementById("replacement-price-1").innerHTML = "200";
document.getElementById("replacement-price-2").innerHTML = "220";
} else if (200 < loose && loose < 300) {
 document.getElementById("premium-price-1").innerHTML = "22";
document.getElementById("premium-price-2").innerHTML = "25";
document.getElementById("deductible-price-1").innerHTML = "125";
document.getElementById("deductible-price-2").innerHTML = "135";
document.getElementById("replacement-price-1").innerHTML = "220";
document.getElementById("replacement-price-2").innerHTML = "230";
} else {
document.getElementById("premium-price-1").innerHTML = "25";
document.getElementById("premium-price-2").innerHTML = "29";
document.getElementById("deductible-price-1").innerHTML = "130";
document.getElementById("deductible-price-2").innerHTML = "145";
document.getElementById("replacement-price-1").innerHTML = "240";
document.getElementById("replacement-price-2").innerHTML = "270";
}
```

Here is a JSFiddlewith the code: https://jsfiddle.net/fxbopt1h/

The idea behind all this is to be placed on different pages and based on the X value of every page to show the proper 6 numbers in the table.

I hope I explain everything and I know maybe it is a dumb approach but please help me do it in the right way.

Comment: IS there any formula for the prices? like if x = 200 so the price is x - 20?

Comment: @Art3mix no formula or calculations, just pure ranges like this _200< loose && loose < 300_. X which is the number in <span> is always fixed number on every page

Comment: IF there are no formula, and all the the prices are raw without any pattern, you can only do it like you did above and add all 13 ranges, you can create a function and pass it the prices so you will write it only once and not 13 times, but still nothing else without any pattern

Comment: @Art3mix not sure that I know how to do this function. Also don't know who to attach the number to the var, because the way is done not it takes the class but not the number I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value, you better put an input there and not a span

```
<input id="price-amount" type="number"/>
```

and to get that value, you can simply do this

```
var loose = document.getElementById("price-amount").value;
```

If there is no pattern, we can't do a function that calculate the prices, so you will have to add them manually (or get it from database if needed).

But what we can do is to add a function, that you pass the prices to it, this will give us only 1 function to write and the IFs:

```
var loose = document.getElementById("price-amount").value;

function setPrices(p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6) {
  document.getElementsById('premium-price-1').textContent = p1;
  document.getElementsById('premium-price-2').textContent = p2;
  document.getElementsById('deductible-price-1').textContent = p3;
  document.getElementsById('deductible-price-2').textContent = p4;
  document.getElementsById('replacement-price-1').textContent = p5;
  document.getElementsById('replacement-price-2').textContent = p6;
}
```

After you set up the function, you can now simply call the function with the right parameters to change the prices in your IFs

```
if (100 < loose && loose < 200) {
  setPrices(18, 20, 120, 130, 200, 220);
} else if (200 < loose && loose < 300) {
  setPrices(22, 25, 125, 135, 220, 230);
} else {
  setPrices(25, 29, 130, 140, 240, 270)
}
```

That way, if you need to change the function you only do it in one place, and its more readable, just make sure you pass the right numbers in the right order for the function.

**NOTE-** please notice that your IFs ranges are only `200 > x < 300`, so if the price will be exactly 200, it will go to the else and not into the range, to change it you need to test for equality as well `200 >= x <= 300`.

```
if (loose >= 100 && loose < 200) {} else if (loose >= 200 && loose < 300) {}
```

**Update**

If you can't change the part of the span, you will need to get its text.

```
var loose = document.getElementById("price-amount").textContent;
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9suq0pg/9/

**Update 2**

You also need to check if the span is a number to make sure no errors will pop up.

if(!isNaN(loose)) {}

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9suq0pg/10/

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Like I wrote in the question I am not good in JS and I try using your JS and replacing mine and now values remain the default ones. I know maybe it is not good to just copy and paste but I really do not understand what is expected to do in order your JS code to work. Here is JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nf275oa3/

Comment: See the updated answer including the change of the number from SPAN to INPUT.

Comment: And still not working I think. Please see the JS Fiddle from my last comment

Comment: Also cannot change is part of the web page which shows X number.

Comment: You are right it wasn't working, and i'm now looking for the reason, but you can see this fiddle is working: https://jsfiddle.net/b9suq0pg/7/